# Automatic sharing rules for related objects

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule

I have a custom object `My_Object__c`.
This object has a lookup to `Account` and it's OWD is `Private`.

I want to make it so whenever an Account `Owner` changes, they can get `Read/Write` access to `My_Object__c` that is related to `Account` they own.

There may be more than 10K of `My_Object__c` so using Process Builder to update owner fails.
I can not change the `My_Object__c` to Master-Detail because some `My_Object__c` may not have an `Account` at all.

Is there a way to configure a sharing rule to satisfy this criteria?

**UPDATE** To be clear, i do NOT want to change owners or manipulate records, I just want the visibility (sharing) to be driven by this `Lookup` relationship.

Comment: You have to validate owner otherwise it will fail; another option is to write apex (change owner for specific criteria only) and call via process builder. sorry mate, I can't comment as I dont have enough reputation. Answer to your limit question is to use Queuable and Batchable. Here is an example you can follow. URL: jamessimone.net/blog/joys-of-apex/batchable-and-queueable-apex Let me know how you go with it; I am sure, this will solve the problem as we had similar scenario on previous project, and we used Queuable and Batchable.

Comment: Just a comment, are you familiar with data skew? Salesforce recommends that you don't have more then 10,000 child records to one parent. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/large-data-volumes/design-your-data-model

Comment: @Kasper this is exactly why this is not a master-child, but a looku

Comment: I fear there is also something called lookup skew https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/04/managing-lookup-skew-to-avoid-record-lock-exceptions.html

Comment: @Kasper fair enough. Let's say i am not too concerned about this, how would I go about approaching what i need?

I do not WANT to change owners, i just want the visibility to be driven by lookup, is all

Comment: @RajeshKumarPunjabi Welcome to the site - converted your answer to a comment for now as it seems the best fit, but it's a quirk of the site that you can't comment without rep. Hope you stick around!

Comment: @zaitsman I fear I don't actually know if you can use sharing rules for that. I haven't had much use for them yet.

Comment: @zaitsman have you looked into apex sharing?

Comment: @TylerZika you mean creating `__Share` records? that has a 10k limit in the transaction as well